# How to reduce the indentation between first and second line inside circle?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

This issue really was causing me troubles.

I have a circle. That circle is a square with **border-radius: 50%**. It's also flex.

The first line contains an icon, the second line has text.

My problem is that they have large indentation between, I'd like them to be closer to each other. I can't come up with an idea how to fix this.

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsanw7oL/7/)

**HTML**

```
<ion-content has-header="false">
  <div class="dashboard-grey-menu">
  <div class="flex row no-padding">
   <div class="col">
     <div class="circle" ui-sref='clients'>
       <div class="ion-ionic"></div>
       <div>Second line</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

**CSS**

```
.dashboard-grey-menu {
  height: 23vh;
  background-color: #959595;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 18vw;
  height: 18vh;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

How would you solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1: add `style="padding-bottom:8vh` to your second div
Solution 2: delete `justify-content: space-around;` from .circle in css because main reason for this space is that one. U should do it with using padding or margin css commands with using vh to not lose responsivilty

Comment: In the second case alignment brakes.

Comment: it can be used padding top to first one, but the circle normally not responsive,it is given that both width and height same value , if circle is maked responsive and works well ,padding top can be.